# Creating dynamic <TD> and adding onMouseOver property

Tags: javascript

I am creating elements in DOM using Javascript in my page like this

```
var myTd_1 = document.createElement("td")
```

and adding properties to them, say

```
myTd_1.width='25%'
myTd_1.padding = '6'
```

and I really want to add different background-color to the TD in case using onMouseOver
and onMouseOut events.

How can I do it ?

I tried looking for it on the net but could not really found what I need.

The closest I came up using what I know is :

```
myTd_1.onMouseOver = 'this.style.backgroundColor="#042b2b"'
myTd_1.onMouseOut = 'this.style.backgroundColor="transparent"'
```

But it's not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is add event listeners to the element for the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events. You can do this using `addEventListener`:

```
var myTd_1 = document.createElement("td");

myTd_1.width='25%';
myTd_1.padding = '6';

document.getElementById('targetrow').appendChild(myTd_1);

myTd_1.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor="#042b2b";
});
myTd_1.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
});
```

Comment: thanks bro, it works!! i figured it has to be something more complex like adding this event listener, and that "this" would not work on creating dynamic <td>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   myTd_1.onmouseover = function() {
      myTd1.style.backgroundColor = "#042b2b";
   }

   myTd_1.onmouseout = function() {
      myTd1.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
   }
```

Comment: i think your function, this way written, will work too....i stick with the 1st answer I got where addEventListener works out great!

Answer (score 1):

try this ....

```
myTd_1.onmouseover = 'this.style.backgroundColor="#042b2b"';
myTd_1.onmouseout = 'this.style.backgroundColor="transparent"';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using the ids in a more dynamic way.

Here is a live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nameIsNull/7hWfx/5/)

Here is the code I used:

```
/* get the table td elements */
var tdCollection = document.getElementById('main').getElementsByTagName('td'),
    i = 0,
    bgClassName = 'mouseover';

function removeClass(element, className) {
    element.className = element.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' +  className + '(\\s|$)', 'g'), '');
}

while (tdCollection[i]) {
    tdCollection[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        /* adding the class to change bgcolor */
        this.className += ' mouseover'; 
    });
    tdCollection[i++].addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        /* removing the bgcolor changing class */
        removeClass(this, bgClassName);  
    });
};
​
```